# Install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on Xen hypervisor with linux kernel 3.18

Tags: kernel, 18.04, xen

Is it possible to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a xen hypervisor platform with a 3.18 kernel?
Does the xen hypervisor's kernel need to be the same or higher then the installed guest?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Don't have an full answer for this but I've tested and its possible.